# Rest api vs sqoop

Tags: rest, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I was trying to import data from `mysql` to `hdfs`.
I was able to do it with `sqoop` but this can be done by fetching the data from *api* also.

My question is about when to use **rest api** to load data in hdfs instead of `sqoop`?

Please specify some difference with use cases!

Comment: What do you mean when saying "rest api"? Api of which service that is?

Comment: Question is to get the use cases in which we can basically use Rest API and load that data into HDFS to analyse? @facha

Comment: what does that mean @MohammadrezaPanahi

Comment: @RahulGoyal i didn't know when i commented!! i think i did a mistake Unintentional while reviewing the questions in my panel. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Sqoop** (SQL <=> Hadoop) is basically used for loading data from **RDBMS to HDFS**.

It's a direct connection to database where you can append/modify/delete data in table(s) using sqoop eval command if privileges are not defined properly for the user accessing the db from sqoop

But using **Rest web services api** we can fetch data from various databases (**can be NoSQL or RDBMS both**) connected internally via code.

Consider you are calling a getUsersData restful web service using curl command which is specifically designed only to provide users data and doesn't allow to append/modify/update any components of db irrespective of database (RDBMS/NoSQL)

Comment: Sqoop2 has a REST API, though, so... The lines are crossed

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sqoop to pull data from Mysql and into Hbase, then put a REST API over Hbase (on Hadoop)... Would be not much different than a REST API over Mysql.

Basically, you're comparing two different things. Hadoop is not meant to replace traditional databases or N-tier user-facing applications, it just is a more distributed, fault tolerant place to store large amounts of data.

And you typically wouldn't use a REST API to talk to a database, then put those values into Hadoop, because that wouldn't be distributed and all database results go through a single process